# How to grow a UIContainerViewCell to the entire page size in landscape view

Tags: ios, user-interface, segue, uiwindow

I'm trying to present a modal ViewController with a custom segue. When the user taps a UIContainerViewCell, I want to grow the cell to the modal page size(covering the navigation bar). I can do this in portrait mode, but when I add things to the UIWindow in landscape mode, the position is messed up and the view is rotated.

Is there a way to either do a custom modal transition without adding a view to the app's window, or a way to rotate the window in order to position the view correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating my own custom modal transition